# Can we make UML object diagrams using UmpleOnline?

Tags: uml, umple

A UML object diagram contains specific real objects and  links to show relationships. The objects are merely instances of classes.
Why bother to make an object model? The multiplicity rules in the class diagram are adhered to in the object diagram. So, object diagrams are sometimes used to validate the class model. If the object model invalidates the class model, then the class model may have to change.

My question: How can I make something that looks like an classic UML Object Model using Umpleonline ?

Example shown below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in Umple to generate instance diagrams. The hope is that it will be ready in early 2022, as it is being worked on by a contributor.

It is issue 510 https://github.com/umple/umple/issues/510

Answer (score -1):

Why not a class diagram with only the names of the classes.
You can skip interfaces but keep abstract/static classes.

Comment: Hi martinlvovlv

Comment: I have been using class diagrams as a substitute for true object diagrams. I just added a new picture to my original posting - take a look. That picture represents what is ideal for my situation.

Comment: Oh, usually I use Astah for diagrams. There you have non-class diagram lines in a class diagram. No idea about Umpleonline .
Sorry, I hope I have been helpful !